# How to center embedded Google Map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a fancybox that loads remote page via AJAX. This page uses JQuery Tabs plugin. On the tab that is not activated by default there is an embedded Google Map. The code that calls Google Maps is

```
<iframe width="740" height="380" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?z=16&amp;t=m&amp;q=<?= $geo['latitude'] ?>+<?= $geo['longitude'] ?>&amp;hl=ru&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

The result map shows the searched location in a top left corner. I want to center the map in coordinates `$geo['latitude']` and `$geo['longitude']`.

I tried to add different query parameters like `ll`, `sll`, but with no success. I also tried to set iframe preload setting of Fancybox to false - no result.
What should I do?

Comment: are you loading the page in fancybox via `iframe`? if not, fancybox iframe preload false won't work. Since the map is in an iframe, is it centered outside fancybox (if you load the page in another page via ajax, does the map come centered)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
<iframe width="740" height="380" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Museum+near+Washington,+United+States&amp;aq=0&amp;sll=40.702863,-74.055748&amp;sspn=0.025669,0.055747&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Museum&amp;hnear=Washington+D.C.,+District+of+Columbia&amp;ll=38.913976,-77.05111&amp;spn=0.052698,0.111494&amp;t=h&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=4718114823360363843&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Play around with the `ll` parameters to center your map.

Also did you have a look at the official [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) ?