# How do you shift the centre of the map in an embedded Google map?

Tags: google-maps

I have a Google Map that I have embedded on my web site. I have managed to size and position the iFrame so that it sits where I want it to sit on my web page. I am using the new Google Maps version.

However, I want to be able to shift the centre of the map to the right, because as it standsnow, the box that displays the map layers is covering some of the locations I have marked.

I am not at this point using any Javascript or jQuery. I have simply taken the iFrame link provided by Google's embed feature and placed it in my HTML. I see there are [other questions about map centering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18205745/184108), but I can't parse them for my situation because they assume some Javascript implementation. Also, I'm hoping that I do not have to take on a whole API or Javascript library to solve this. Further, it is unclear to me if the other questions relate to the new Google Maps version, which is what I'm using.

Is there a way I can alter the centre of the embedded Google Map?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a "center" parameter to your iframe url. Like so - `center="40.714728,-73.998672"`. You can get the required coordinates by searching in google maps and picking them from the address.

You could alternatively also use a query parameter but center is more accurate.

refer - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#location